# plpgsql function to search and move index in array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to write a function to find elements ahead from given positions of given elements in a two dimensional array. basically it involves steps of finding all the positions in array for given element and move the positions a few steps back.

I have created a function to return all matches of the element. But need to modify the function to be able to move the index a few positions back from the position of given element.

see details below:

```
dev=# \d+ test
                          Table "public.test"
 Column  |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id      | integer |           | plain    |              |
 actions | text[]  |           | extended |              |

dev=# select * from test;
 id |                                                actions
----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {{a,1,1,1},{b,3,2,3},{c,2,3,4},{d,5,6,7},{e,3,4,5},{f,6,7,8},{g,0,9,0},{a,2,3,4},{k,3,4,5},{a,2,3,7}}
(1 row)

--function to get element of current position
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_in_array(needle ANYELEMENT, haystack ANYARRAY,OUT cname text,out val1 numeric,out val2 numeric,out val3 numeric)
RETURNS setof record
  AS $$   
SELECT $2[i][1],$2[i][2]::numeric,$2[i][3]::numeric,$2[i][4]::numeric
    FROM generate_series(array_lower($2,1), array_upper($2,1)) AS i
     WHERE $2[i][1] = $1;   
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;


dev=# select find_in_array('a',actions) from test;
 find_in_array
---------------
 (a,1,1,1)
 (a,2,3,4)
 (a,2,3,7)
(3 rows)
```

Now, given element a, I'd like to find the elements about 2-3 positions ahead from letter 'a' (if find the element with same letter, skip it). in the example, it would be:
(e,3,4,5)
(f,6,7,8)
(a,2,3,4) --skipped, because it's got same letter a.
(g,0,9,0)

based on answer from @Ziggy, I modified the above function to make it move back a few positions. Further from the current code, if there's a match positioned at the first element of the array, I hope to return a row like 'direct',0,0,0

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_in_array_move(needle ANYELEMENT, haystack ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS TABLE (cname text, val1 numeric, val2 numeric, val3 numeric)
  AS $$
    SELECT case when i=1 then 'direct' else $2[i-i_move][1] end,
    case when i=1 then 0 else $2[i-i_move][2]::numeric end,
    case when i=1 then 0 else $2[i-i_move][3]::numeric end,
    case when i=1 then 0 else $2[i-i_move][4]::numeric end
    FROM generate_series(2, 3) i_move,
         generate_series(array_lower($2,1), array_upper($2,1)) AS i
    WHERE $2[i][1] = $1
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

The result is:

```
 dev=# select find_in_array_move('a',actions) from test;
 find_in_array_move
--------------------
 (direct,0,0,0)
 (direct,0,0,0)
 (f,6,7,8)
 (e,3,4,5)
 (a,2,3,4)
 (g,0,9,0)
 (,,,)
 (,,,)
 (,,,)
 (,,,)
(10 rows)
```

the expected result is (note that I cannot do a distinct as I would allow duplicated rows of "non direct" records):

```
 find_in_array_move
--------------------
 (direct,0,0,0)
 (f,6,7,8)
 (e,3,4,5)
 (a,2,3,4)
 (g,0,9,0)
```

any suggestion?

Comment: don't use "move" as variable name it's a reserved word.

Comment: Thank you Rémy. I changed the variable name, now the error is:

    dev=# select find_in_array_move('a',actions) from test;

    ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
    HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
    CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function find_in_array_move(anyelement,anyarray) line 6 at SQL statement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't SELECT to results from a plpgsql function. You must use RETURN QUERY:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_in_array_move(needle ANYELEMENT, haystack ANYARRAY,OUT cname text,out val1 numeric,out val2 numeric,out val3 numeric)
 RETURNS setof record AS $$
declare 
  i_move int;
begin
  for i_move in 2..5 loop
    RETURN QUERY
      SELECT $2[i-i_move][1],$2[i-i_move][2]::numeric,$2[i-i_move][3]::numeric,$2[i-i_move][4]::numeric
      FROM generate_series(array_lower($2,1), array_upper($2,1)) AS i
      WHERE $2[i][1] = $1;
  end loop;
  RETURN;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Also, depending on your PostgreSQL version, you might be able to use the equivalent RETURNS TABLE, which ismuch more elegant and easier to maintain than using OUT parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_in_array_move(needle ANYELEMENT, haystack ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS TABLE (cname text, val1 numeric, val2 numeric, val3 numeric)
  AS $$
...
```

Finally, a plpgsql LOOP is not needed if you simply use `generate_series` instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_in_array_move(needle ANYELEMENT, haystack ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS TABLE (cname text, val1 numeric, val2 numeric, val3 numeric)
  AS $$
    SELECT $2[i-i_move][1],$2[i-i_move][2]::numeric,$2[i-i_move][3]::numeric,$2[i-i_move][4]::numeric
    FROM generate_series(2, 5) i_move,
         generate_series(array_lower($2,1), array_upper($2,1)) AS i
    WHERE $2[i][1] = $1
    ORDER BY i_move, i;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Comment: Thank  you Ziggy. I guess it's probably because my postgresql version is too old, 8.2. as it throws error. I updated the original post with the error message.

Comment: @fairybetty Yes, it's a new feature in version 9+. You can still mix your original interface (with OUT parameters) and the SQL function (the last one) for better performance than using a LOOP.

Comment: Hi Ziggy, the last version of the function you provided works perfectly on my database, no errors thrown out. I'm checking the result and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Ziggy, is there a better way to remove the calculated subscript (i-i_move) of array that not exist?

Comment: @fairybetty perhaps using `AND $2[i-i_move] IS NOT NULL` in the WHERE clause?

Comment: I've created the desired function based on Ziggy's suggestion. Thus, I'll accept the answer. Thanks a lot Ziggy!